Change default IME to a custom IME when building a custom ROM
I've developed a custom keyboard (IME) for Android that I can install and use on the device without any issues.
The next step I want to take is to set this keyboard as the default input method in a custom AOSP build that I'm working on.
I'm having trouble figuring out what changes I need to make in the AOSP source code to achieve this.
Any guidance on how to make my custom keyboard the default would be really appreciated.

Eventually, I found that there are multiple ways to replace the default IME in AOSP.
The approaches I considered include:

Changing the default LatinIME source code.
Modifying the source code of InputMethodManagerService to select the custom IME.
Updating System.Secure properties so the InputMethodManagerService would select the custom IME.
Other possible approaches that I may not be aware of.

I chose to update the System.Secure properties at boot, specifically enabled_input_methods and default_input_method. This method allows the custom IME to be set as default without altering the core AOSP code, making it easier to maintain.
To implement this, I used the settings put secure command within the device's init.rc script, which runs a bash script at boot to execute the necessary settings commands.
Here's what the init.rc looks like:
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    ...
    start vendor.boot_start_sh

service vendor.boot_start_sh /vendor/bin/boot_start.sh
    class main
    user root
    group root system
    disabled
    oneshot

The init.rc file is located under the device folder for the specific device you're building for.
An example init.rc for dragonboard is located here.
This init.rc script triggers a boot_start.sh script upon boot completion:
#!/system/bin/sh
settings put secure enabled_input_methods com.my_custom_ime.package/.CustomIMEService
settings put secure default_input_method com.my_custom_ime.package/.CustomIMEService

These changes ensure that the settings are initialized so that InputMethodManagerService reads them and selects the custom IME instead of relying on its built-in logic.
If anyone has experience with other methods or suggestions to improve this approach, I'd love to hear your thoughts!

Have you worked on multi ime /multi keyboard display in both primary and secondary display? If yes, Let me know which source code modification made in AOSP 14?
